# Copying of type struct Improver.Activity memory[] memory to storage not yet supported

Tags: solidity

Im creating a smart contract where an user creates activities and then adds them in to a routine. When i compile my code i get this error:

> Copying of type struct Improver.Activity memory[] memory to storage
> not yet supported

I tried to look at other questions similar to this one but i couldn't fix the issue.

**Code:**

```
    //SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
    
    contract Improver {
        struct User {
            string username;
            address _address;
            string profilePic;
            uint id;
        }
    
        struct Activity {
            address owner;
            uint start;
            uint end;
            bool status;
            string activity;
            uint id;
        }
    
        struct Routine {
            Activity[] activities;
            bool areActivitiesAllDone;
            address owner;
            uint id;
        }
    
        User[] public usersArray;
        Activity[] public activityArray;
        Routine[] public routineArray;
        mapping(address => User) public addressToUser;
        mapping(string => User) public nameToUser;
        mapping(address => Activity) public addressToActivity;
        mapping(uint => Activity) public idToActivity;
        mapping(address => Routine) public addressToRoutine;
        mapping(uint => Routine) public idToRoutine;
    
        
        function createActivity(
            uint _start,
            uint _end,
            string memory _activity
        ) public {
            Activity memory newActivity = Activity({
                owner: msg.sender,
                start: _start,
                end: _end,
                status: false,
                activity: _activity,
                id: activityArray.length
            });
    
            addressToActivity[msg.sender] = newActivity;
            activityArray.push(newActivity);
        }

            function createRoutine(uint[] memory activitiesID) public {
        Activity[] memory routineActivities = new Activity[](8);
        bool[] memory activitiesStatus = new bool[](8);
        bool areAllActivitiesDone;

        // Puts activities in the array (routineActivities)
        for (uint index; index < activitiesID.length; index++) {
            Activity memory activity = idToActivity[index];
            routineActivities[routineActivities.length] = activity;
        }

        // Puts all activities status in an array (activitiesStatus)
        for (uint index; index < activitiesID.length; index++) {
            Activity memory activity = idToActivity[index];
            activitiesStatus[activitiesStatus.length] = activity.status;
        }

        // Checks if all activities are done or not and then set a variable depending on the results
        for (uint index; index < activitiesStatus.length; index++) {
            bool status = activitiesStatus[index];
            if (status == false) {
                areAllActivitiesDone = false;
            } else {
                areAllActivitiesDone = true;
            }
        }

        // Create a routine
        Routine memory newRoutine = Routine({
            activities: routineActivities,
            areActivitiesAllDone: areAllActivitiesDone,
            owner: msg.sender,
            id: routineArray.length
        });

        // Add the routine to the different mappings and arrays
        addressToRoutine[newRoutine.owner] = newRoutine;
        idToRoutine[newRoutine.id] = newRoutine;
        routineArray.push(newRoutine);
    }
}

    
   
    }
```

The function that's causing the problem is `createRoutine()`, the last one.
If you have an

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because its not possible to copy a struct containing a dynamic array to storage. But you can build it. Replace the last lines with this:

```
    // Create a routine

    // Add the routine to the different mappings and arrays
    uint256 routineArrayIdx = routineArray.length;
    routineArray.push();
    Routine storage routineByArray = routineArray[routineArrayIdx];
    
    Routine storage routineByAddress = addressToRoutine[msg.sender];
    Routine storage routineById = idToRoutine[routineArrayIdx];

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < routineActivities.length; i++) {
        routineByAddress.activities.push(routineActivities[i]);
        routineById.activities.push(routineActivities[i]);
        routineByArray.activities.push(routineActivities[i]);
    }
    
    routineByAddress.areActivitiesAllDone = areAllActivitiesDone;
    routineByAddress.owner = msg.sender;
    routineByAddress.id = routineArrayIdx;
    
    routineById.areActivitiesAllDone = areAllActivitiesDone;
    routineById.owner = msg.sender;
    routineById.id = routineArrayIdx;

    routineByArray.areActivitiesAllDone = areAllActivitiesDone;
    routineByArray.owner = msg.sender;
    routineByArray.id = routineArrayIdx;
```